# Changing Distance and Linkage of a heat map

Tags: r, heatmap, euclidean-distance, linkage

I am trying to change the distance and linkage of my heat map from the standard
Euclidean Distance and Complete linkage to any other setting for a question in my homework.

We are using this data set:

```
library("flexclust")
data(milk)
help(milk)
```

this is my current code:

```
hm3<-heatmap(milk_matrix, scale="column", main="Heat map of the Composition of Mammals' Milk", xlab= "Nutrient", ylab = "Animal", cexRow = 0.6, cexCol = 1.1, col=heat.colors(10))
legend(x= "bottomright", legend=c("min", "med", "max"),  cex = 0.6, fill=heat.colors(3))
```

R help for heat map says you can change the distance/ linkage by:

distfun=
and
hclustfun=

but I have had no luck typing something such as hclustfun= "single".

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! I can specify any distance or linkage as long as it is not Euclidean Distance and Complete linkage.

Kind Regards,
Rosie :)

heat map changing distance and linkage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `distfun` and `hclustfun` arguments you have to use options already available in the `stats::dist()` and `stats::hclust()` (check their help). So for example for `distfun` based on "maximum" distance measure instead of the default "euclidean" you can use the following:

```
# dist method must be one of "euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "binary" or "minkowski"

heatmap(as.matrix(milk), 
        scale="column", 
        main="Heat map of the Composition of Mammals' Milk", 
        xlab= "Nutrient", 
        ylab = "Animal", 
        cexRow = 0.6, 
        cexCol = 1.1, 
        col=heat.colors(10),
        distfun = function(x) dist(x, method = "maximum"))
legend(x= "bottomright", legend=c("min", "med", "max"),  cex = 0.6, fill=heat.colors(3))
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this code: ``` h3<- heatmap(milk_matrix, 
        scale="column", 
        main="Heat map of the Composition of Mammals' Milk", 
        xlab= "Nutrient", 
        ylab = "Animal", 
        cexRow = 0.6, 
        cexCol = 1.1, 
        col=heat.colors(10),
        distfun = function(x) dist(x, method = "minkowski"))
legend(x= "bottomright", legend=c("min", "med", "max"),  cex = 0.6, fill=heat.colors(3)) ```            and it worked. But my graph came out the same as the one i created with Euclidean distance - is this to be expected or have i done something wrong??

Comment: Depends on the data, overall it is possible that result of two clustering methods be the same. If you’re not sure your code is working or not check different methods to see if they all yield the same result or not